# Collection was modified error when removing a row from a DataTable

Tags: c#

I am trying to loop through a `DataTable` and during that loop I am comparing each row to another `DatabTable` and then if the record matches remove the row. The resulting `DataTable` then gets put into a `DataGridView`.

However I am getting the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Collection was modified;
> enumeration operation might not execute.'

Im not 100% sure but I think its because I am modifying the Table that is being looped through? But if that is the case how do i then remove the rows that are duplicates?

My code is as follows:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dtM1.Rows)
{
    int matchCount = 0;
    string id = dr["cmoOrganizationID"].ToString();
    
    foreach (DataRow dr2 in dtSQLite.Rows)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(id + " "+ dr2["sSupplierID"].ToString());
        if (dr2["sSupplierID"].ToString() == id)
        {
            matchCount++;
        }
    }

    if (matchCount > 0) 
    {
        dtM1.Rows.Remove(dr); 
        MessageBox.Show("Item to remove" + id);
    }
}

dgv.DataSource = dtM1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At `dtM1.Rows.Remove(dr)` you remove a row from the `DataTable` that you are currently enumerating. That breaks the loop, hence you get the exception. You cannot modify the underlying collection during enumeration.

One solution is to fill a list and remove the rows afterwards:

```
var removeRows = new List<DataRow>(); // before loop

// in the loop ...
if (matchCount > 0) 
{
    removeRows.Add(dr);
    MessageBox.Show("Item to remove" + id); // don't show MessageBoxes in a loop
}
// rest of loop ...
```

and now remove it after the loop:

```
removeRows.ForEach(dtM1.Rows.Remove);
```

Comment: Thank you that works perfectly! The MessageBox that you mention to remove was just there for testing purposes when I was checking the data in the variable so dont worry it will be removed :)